# Generic method that calls another generic method - util method returns Class<Customer> instead of Customer

Tags: java, generics

I am using `simpleframework` to parse XML string and convert it to an object.

```
Serializer serializer = new Persister();
try {
    Customer model = serializer.read(Customer.class, xmlString);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It works well, however I will have a few classes to convert. I made an util method which I call with:

```
Utils.parseXml(Customer.class, xmlString);
```

And below an implementation:

```
public class Utils {
    public static <T> T parseXml(T cls, String data) {
        Serializer serializer = new Persister();
        T model = null;

        try {
            model = serializer.read(cls, data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return model;
    }
}
```

The problem is that this method returns `Class<Customer>` instead of `Customer` which I expect.

What should I do to get a valid result ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `T cls` in your method definition to `Class<T>`.